# how to implement Elastic Search in Laravel for auto complete

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5

I followed this wonderful tutorial [Made with love ES laravel tutorial](https://madewithlove.com/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-in-your-laravel-app-2019-edition/) to implement ES in my Laravel Ecommerce app i am building. I got it to work but i wanted to tweak it a little because as of now, the results only work when i my query term matches exactly an entire word i have in one of my products.

i have a health nut bar called bear naked almond bar, but when i type "bea" it doesn't match anything, but when i type "bear" then it works.

This is my search query as of now.

```
$model = new ProductsListing;

$items = $this->elasticsearch->search([
    'index' => $model->getSearchIndex(),
    'type' => $model->getSearchType(),
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'fields' => ['brand', 'name^5', 'description'],
                'query' => $query,
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I would need some help to adjust the query so that i get results as i type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get help here: [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/1009)

and this was the perfect solution. Thank you Enricco Zimuel.

```
        $elasticsearch = ClientBuilder::create()
        ->setHosts(config('services.search.hosts'))
        ->build();

        $model = new ProductsListing;


        $items = $elasticsearch->search([
            'index' => $model->getSearchIndex(),
            'type' => $model->getSearchType(),
            'body' => [

                //this helped a lot
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716639/how-to-implement-elastic-search-in-laravel-for-auto-complete

                //using query_string
                'query' => [
                    'query_string' => [
                        // 'fields' => ['brand', 'name^5', 'description'], //notice the weight operator ^5
                        'fields' => ['name'],
                        'query' => $query.'*',
                    ],
                ],

            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `PHP and laravel`, but **the reason why it's not giving result on `bea` b/c you are using match query which applies the same analyzer which is used at index time, and your text `bear naked almond bar` creates `bear`, `naked`, `almond` and `bar` tokens and `bea` doesn't match any token.**

You can change your query below(not sure about the correct syntax for the prefix in laravel).

```
$model = new ProductsListing;
        
$items = $this->elasticsearch->search([
    'index' => $model->getSearchIndex(),
    'type' => $model->getSearchType(),
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'prefix' => [. --> changed to prefix query.
                'fields' => ['brand', 'name^5', 'description'],
                'query' => $query,
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I am assuming that you are using the `text` field with default `standard` analyzer and using the [analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API, you can check the tokens generated for your text.

POST your-index/_analyze

```
{
    "text": "bear naked almond bar",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "bear",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "naked",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "almond",
            "start_offset": 11,
            "end_offset": 17,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "bar",
            "start_offset": 18,
            "end_offset": 21,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing your syntax without luck, not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @NicolasZein, I don't hv exp. with php syntax, but I can provide search JSON if thats fine for you, also did you get a chance to look at blog which discuss the internals of different approach?

Comment: yes i did but i was not able to make it work. Someone on elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php helped me and it worked perfectly, i added the solution. You can check it.

Comment: @NicolasZein, just looked into the solution, which is using wildcard querie which are very costly, IMHO prefix query would have been a better solution.

Comment: it's not wildcard but query_string. It's extremely fast as i can notice.

Comment: @NicolasZein, please note the wildcard in your search term `  'query' => $query.'*',` which would make it slow, as of now looks like you don't have much documents, hence you don't see the performance degradation but with huge index you will notice it, As a best practice we should avoid wildcard queries.

Comment: I see, ok thanks. Yes indeed i have only a few items presently, i will keep that in mind, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try `match_phrase_prefix` with `must query inside bool` query  instead of `multi_match` ... you will start getting result as you type...

**e.g**

```
$query = '{
          "size": 10, //size of return array 
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "tag":"' . $filter_name . '"
                    }
                }
              ],
            }
          }
        }';

//Now pass this $query variable to your ES request
```

there are two methods 1- `prefix` , 2- `match_phrase_prefix`

Please see documentation for [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) and [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)

Comment: Hello Muhammad and thanks for your help. Is this laravel notation? The syntax doesn't work. I'm using elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php in my laravel app. Even if i replace your semicolon with arrows it's not accepting it.

Comment: arrow was just to tell you about the sub feature of `bool` query... just study the code i attached with my answer and modify it according to your laravel... my code is in simple core php... i make a DSL query and store it in variable and then pass it to ES function to search...

Comment: @NicolasZein, if you have access to kibana ...please copy and paste my query (change field name to yours) and run by start searching with 1 letter then 2 letter then 3 letters...hope you wiull get results...

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar, match phrase prefix would not work if you have query like `bear alm` etc, it makes prefix query on the last term and phrase search on the initial terms

Comment: @NicolasZein add Fuzziness also ... bcz `match_phrase_prefix` search from start of keyword..so if you add fuzziness then it will give you exception of 1 or 2 letters...

Comment: So guys, it's ok to go a different route, how do you think i need to do my query to get a proper response. How do other people do query suggestions?